# Как сделать таблицу внутри таблицы в html?

Tags: html, table, таблицы

Мне нужна такая же таблица, как изображена на картинке, но я понятия пока не имею, как именно сделать таблицу внутри самой таблицы[image: таблица, которую нужно сделать]

Вот то, что я набросал:

```html
<table width="60%"
       border="10"
       cellpadding="3"
       cellspacing="3">
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="3">8</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>11</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>13</td>
  <td>14</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>15</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>17</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td colspan="2">6</td>
  <td>7</td>
</table>
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: Можно поместить тег `<table>` в тег `<td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что-то по типу такого. Найдете нужную ячейку и вставите таблицу. Показал на вашем примере. Как вставить таблицу в таблицу

```html
<table width="60%"
       border="10"
       cellpadding="3"
       cellspacing="3">
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="3"> <table width="60%"
       border="10"
       cellpadding="3"
       cellspacing="3"></td>
  <td>8.1</td>
  <td>8.2</td>
  <td>8.3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>11</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>13</td>
  <td>14</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>15</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>17</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td colspan="2">6</td>
  <td>7</td>
</table>
```

А так мир уже давно не пользуется таблицами в веб. Используйте [`<div>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css) чтоб нарисовать таблицу